# Windows 10/11 vs Windows Server as Virtual Machine

Tags: windows-10, windows-11, windows-server-2022

I am using Windows 11 Laptop with high configuration 32 vCPUs, 96 GB RAM). I have VMs deployed on it using VMware Workstation Pro which I use for work and personal use. I am using Windows 10 VM for my work. But when using Windows 10, I found that it only works with 2 vCPUs even if I gave 4. Because of this, I sometimes have cracking sound in Audio and video is not smooth. I installed Windows Server 2022 and it is so smooth. I am able to run Apps and run video so smoothly without issues.

So is it better to use Windows Server as a daily PC? Is there a way for Win 10 VM to add more CPUs? Does it improve if I use Windows 11?

Comment: so how many VMs do you have running at once, and do the sum of them virtual cores ever exceed your physical core count (which is definitely not 932)? I ask because sometimes, counter-intuitively, adding additional cores to a VM does not improve its performance unless the host has plenty that are not in use. the way VmWare products handle symmetric multi-threading, no execution time will be granted on any core until the host is idle on the full number of cores assigned to the vm. this can cause a delay while the host is waiting for that condition to be met.

Comment: Sorry for the typo. Its 32 vCPUs. No, I am not exceeding my CPU count. I am running that Windows 10 VM alone and still face this issue.

Comment: @JOKER That seems like a VMware Workstation Pro issue - have you considered using Hyper-V, as that has no such limitation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a Windows 10 VM using VMware Workstation Pro V17 and I experience the Audio issue you have occasionally.

In the VMware menu, in VM Settings (Windows 10 VM shut down), under Processors, you can set Number of CPUs and Cores per CPU.  I have 4 currently, so you can use more if you wish.

I am using a Windows 11 Pro host. The Windows 11 Pro host works smoothly no matter what is happening with my VMs.

I run 4 machines simultaneously.

Windows 10 is older in design (at at the end of life) than either Windows 11 Pro or Server 2022. I don't think you can do much with Windows 10 because it is near end of life, so I suggest not using it as guest or host for heavy work.

Probably Windows 11 Pro will work fine and will more user Apps you may like than Server 2022.

If  Server 2022 does all you wish, and works better for you as your daily machine, consider it as your host.

Comment: Yeah. My host is Win 11 Pro. So you are using Win 11 Pro VM on Win 11 Host and not facing any Audio issues? Does Win 11 VM run better than Win 10 VM?

Comment: I had no issues with a Windows 11 VM but since I have Windows 11 as a host, I do not use the VM any more.  It tends to be better to use the system you use most as host.

Comment: I have seen your comments and in my answer suggested Server 2022 as host if that works better for you. My Windows 11 machine is fine, but different users see different results    @JOKER

Answer (score 1):

I'm currently using a Windows 10 VM on Windows 11 and can allocate
4 virtual processors. My own setting is:

- Number of processors: 2
- Number of cores per processor: 2
- Total processor cores: 4

This works fine.

Have a look into
[Virtual CPU Configuration and Limitations](https://docs.vmware.com/en/VMware-vSphere/8.0/vsphere-vm-administration/GUID-3CDA4DEF-3DE0-4A64-89C7-F31BB77222CB.html),
to see if one of the clauses applies to your case.
(However, I would think it unlikely.)

Question : Where do you see that only two vCPU are running?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I am seeing in the output of `dxdiag` and also in PC settings, About screen.

Comment: You have no issues when Audio is playing in the VM? Like no crackling sound?

Comment: I have made some tests. Is perhaps your Windows 10 version is Home? I found that only Windows 10 Pro can have more than 2 vCPUs.

Comment: I am using Win 10 Pro. I tested on Win 11 Pro VM and having same issues.

Comment: My tests show the Home limit is 2, the Pro limit is 4, Windows Server is much less limited (I haven't hit the maximum with my tests).

Answer (score 0):

After some digging around and trying out the Windows Server VM, here is what I found:

```
Windows 10/11 Home VM limited to 1 vCPU.

Windows 10/11 Pro VM limited to 2 vCPU.

Windows Server 2022 VM is limited to 64 vCPU.
```

I have tried setting the following on Windows 10 VM:

No. of Processors: 2
No. of cores per processor: 2

Total processor cores: 4 and RAM is 16 GB. Host has total 32 vCPUs and 96 GB RAM.

But this resulted in Audio issues like crackling sounds. Also, this way I am seeing problems with display where if I maximize or go full screen of any video or application, screen goes black for 2 - 3 seconds and come back. So basically, it's not smooth.

Deployed WS 2022 VM with 4 vCPUs and 16 GB RAM, and oh man it is butter smooth. It is faster, loading applications and web pages. No problem with audio and video. Overall much better than Windows 10 VM. Guess I am going to stick with this.

But downside of using Windows Server vs Windows 10/11 is that you don't get PC like applications like Microsoft Store and any applications that want to install from it.

Comment: Deployed WS 2022 VM with 4 vCPUs and 16 GB RAM  ..... I did suggest this as an approach in my answer to you

Comment: @John, Correct. Thanks for the suggestion. I wanted to update on the results and my opinions on the testing.